# How to replace a list item with direct instance assignment

Tags: c#, list

I have the following code where I'm trying 3 approaches (Cases) to update the first item in a C# list(Note: Dump() is a helper output method in the LINQPad IDE). I would appreciate an explanation as to why Case 2 does not succeed in updating the list while Case 3 does. Both first and list[0] are references to the first item in the list and should behave equivalently when assigned a direct reference. Apparently not...

```
void Main()
{
Person first =  null;
List<Person> list = CreateList(out first);

//Case 1
//This updates the list
first.fname = "Third"; 
list.Dump(); //outputs third, second


//Case 2
//This does not update the list
list = CreateList(out first);
first= new Person() { fname="Third"}; 
list.Dump(); //outputs first, second


//Case 3
//This updates the list
list = CreateList(out first);
list[0] = new Person() { fname="Third"}; 
list.Dump(); //outputs third, second

}

List<Person> CreateList(out Person first)
{
  var list = new List<Person>
  {
  new Person() { fname="First", lname = ""},
  new Person() { fname="Second", lname = ""}
  };
  first = list.Find( x => x.fname == "First");
  return list;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Person
{
  public string fname;
  public string lname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second case doesn't work because you change the reference for the `first` to the new object using this code:

```
first= new Person() { fname="Third"};
```

After this code run, the `first` is not refer to list object again.

Try to use this for the second case:

```
list = CreateList(out first);
if(first != null)
   first.fname="Third";
list.Dump();
```

This will set the property of `first` and the `first` is still refer to the list item.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a new object to a reference object

```
first= new Person() { fname="Third"};
```

you generate a new object with a new hashcode upon which the object is identified in collection.the list does not find the previous hascode and thus list is not updated.//case 2

but in case 3 you are replacing the instance of object and thereby list updates the new hash

in case 1 you modify only property of an object and the hash remains intact

may be this be explanation to your problem

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the replies.